# Autocomplete bug in tkinter- HTML editor

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently working on an HTML editor application with Python tkinter. When you create a new project or open an existing file, a text widget is displayed on the screen, along with a `Run` button to run your HTML code. When you type any HTML start tag, the script will immediately add an end tag to that element (autocomplete). I'm using a function called `get_stringvar` that is bound by any key release. That function is in charge of the autocomplete. When I type my first start tag, the script autocompletes the end tag. But when I type my second start tag, the end tag isn't being autocompleted. Can someone help me fix that? Some of my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
from tkinter import messagebox
import webbrowser
import os

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("HTML Editor")
window.configure(bg="grey")
window.state("zoomed")
title = tk.Label(window, text="HTML Editor", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 40, "underline"), bg="grey")
title.place(x=400, y=20)


def get_stringvar(event):
    content = text_box.get("1.0", tk.END)
    keys = ["Return", "Up", "Down", "Left", "Right"]

    if event.keysym in keys:
        return

    line = content.splitlines()[-1]
    if "/" not in line and line != "<!DOCTYPE html>":
        if ("<" in line and ">" in line) and line.index(">") + 1 == len(line):
            index = line.index("<")
            index2 = line.index(">") + 1
            new_line = "<" + "/" + line[index + 1:index2 - 1] + ">"
            text_box.insert(tk.END, new_line)
            line2 = content.splitlines().index(line) + 1
            text_box.mark_set("insert", "%d.%d" % (line2, index2))




create = tk.Button(window, text="Create a new file", width=17, height=3, font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20),
                   command=save_file)
create.place(x=420, y=200)
open_e = tk.Button(window, text="Open an existing file", width=17, height=3, font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20),
                   command=open_file)
open_e.place(x=420, y=350)

window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
frame = tk.Frame(window, bd=2, relief="raised")

text_box = tk.Text(window, font=("Courier New", 10), fg="black")
text_box.bind("<KeyRelease>", get_stringvar)

scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(window, command=text_box.yview)

run_b = tk.Button(frame, text="Run", width=6, height=2, bg="white", command=run_code)

text_box.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set)

window.mainloop()
```

Updated code (Thank you so much, @TheLizzard):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
from tkinter import messagebox
import webbrowser
import os

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("HTML Editor")
window.configure(bg="grey")
window.state("zoomed")
title = tk.Label(window, text="HTML Editor", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 40, "underline"), bg="grey")
title.place(x=400, y=20)


def get_stringvar(event):
    line = text_box.get("insert linestart", "insert")
    if (line[-1] == ">") and ("<" in line):
        new_line = "</" + line[line.rindex("<") + 1:-1] + ">"
        text_box.insert("insert", new_line)
        text_box.mark_set("insert", f"insert-{len(new_line)}c")
        return "break"

create = tk.Button(window, text="Create a new file", width=17, height=3, font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20),
                   command=save_file)
create.place(x=420, y=200)
open_e = tk.Button(window, text="Open an existing file", width=17, height=3, font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20),
                   command=open_file)
open_e.place(x=420, y=350)

window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
frame = tk.Frame(window, bd=2, relief="raised")

text_box = tk.Text(window, font=("Courier New", 10), fg="black")
text_box.bind("<Tab>", get_stringvar)

scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(window, command=text_box.yview)

run_b = tk.Button(frame, text="Run", width=6, height=2, bg="white", command=run_code)

text_box.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please make a minimal working example? Right now we really don't need 1/2 of your code like all of the file saving/opening stuff.

Comment: @TheLizzard, I'll edit some of the code out of the question

Comment: Try binding to `"<KeyRelease>"` instead of `"<KeyPress>"`

Comment: @TheLizzard, it still doesn't work

Comment: @TheLizzard, now it works, even though I didn't change anything.

Comment: I need help with another thing now. I'll edit the question

Comment: I have a few suggestion for the current question. I will post them as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk


def tab_pressed(event):
    line = text_box.get("insert linestart", "insert")
    if (line[-1:] == ">") and ("<" in line):
        new_line = "</" + line[line.rindex("<")+1:-1] + ">"
        text_box.insert("insert", new_line)
        text_box.mark_set("insert", f"insert-{len(new_line)}c")
        # Stop the tab from being added
        return "break"

    # Remove these 2 lines if you like tabs over spaces
    text_box.insert("insert", " "*4)
    return "break"


window = tk.Tk()

text_box = tk.Text(window)
text_box.bind("<Tab>", tab_pressed)
text_box.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(window, command=text_box.yview)
scroll_bar.pack(side="left", fill="y")

text_box.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set)

window.mainloop()
```

Instead of binding to `"<KeyPress>"` or `"<KeyRelease>"`, it will me more user friendly if you bind to `"<Tab>"`. Also your code only works if it's the user is writing on the last line. Instead of using `"end"`, you should use `"insert"`. Also please look at [this](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/text.html#M18) it will help you a lot. Also my code uses `line.rindex("<")` to get the index of the right most `"<"` in the `line`.

The code above autocompletes the html tag only if the user presses `"<Tab>"`. To test it just type in `<aaa>` then press `Tab` (works only if the cursor is after the `>`).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed and well explained answer! It's a good idea to bind `"<Tab>"` instead of `"<KeyRelease>"`. I was stuck with this issue for a couple hours now and it really stumped me. Again, thank you so much for your help

Comment: @Roni No problem, but I only know this because I made an autocompleter for C++ :D

Comment: @Roni btw usually html editors nowadays don't even require you to type `<>` just type the tag name and it places those angle brackets automatically, but sure you can also keep it like this

Comment: @Matiiss I use notepad to make websites... It doesn't have that functionality. So you are saying that if I type in: `p` and then press tab it will convert it to `<p>|</p>` where the `|` is the cursor? I might make that.

Comment: @TheLizzard you don't stop amazing me, first you use IDLE which is not that bad but then here you are using Notepad to write html (or notepad++?) or is the autocomplete global? anyhow, yes that is at least how `PyCharm` and `VSCode` autocomplete, simply type in the letter and press tab, adds brackets and closing tag. Also at least PyCharm for some tags automatically adds the attributes like `src="|"` and puts the cursor between "" and some other stuff probably, I mean, if you can, you should try out, at least to get the funcitonality

Comment: @Matiiss I am not a html developer so the basic MS notepad is good enough for me. Also it doesn't have any auto complete and I never use auto complete even for python. I'd rather type the code instead of having to look through 100 suggestions to find what I am after. I will try adding that functionality to the code.